# Use "Content" outside of main file

Tags: c#, xna

When I try and do something like
`Content.Load<Texture2D>("x");`
outside of the main file, it throws an error saying it doesn't exist in this context, even if I do using
`Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;`
Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the instance of your content manager. Outside of your main class you must have a variable for instance of your content manager, here is what I mean:

```
public class OtherClass
{
      ContentManager content;
      public OtherClass(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
      {
          content = new ContentManager(serviceProvider, "Content");
      }
      public void LoadStuff()
      {
           content.Load<Texture2D>("x");
      }
}

public class Game1
{ 
     public void DoStuff()
     {
         OtherClass other = new OtherClass(Services);
         other.LoadStuff();
     }
}
```